# MVC pattern differences

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, interface

I just need a few links to articles I can read up on or some basic explanations regarding the different patterns used in MVC (C#).

At present I tend to build my web apps using a view model pattern. For every view I have one view model. I like this approach purely because there can be so much junk that is not needed from the model and I can use some basic data annotations here.

I also now construct my viewmodels within the view model itself (Unsure if this is correct?) so that I can keep my controllers as simple as possible.

There are times however I have found myself adding in a lot of logic within my controller, I would assume this is fine also as to me that is what the controller is there for.

Now based on the above as I said I can quite happily build my apps without any major issues. However whilst doing my normal browsing of code examples etc I often find that there are so many other ways out there used by different developers to do essentially what I am doing above and I would like an explanation of they all fit together.

I often see mentioned "use your repository to do blah blah".. I do use repositorys "sometimes" but this is mainly for model querying that I know I will re-use in the future and it always turns in to a bit of a dumping ground. What is best practice here?

I also see mentioned "interfaces" and "service layers" I am totally lost here.. most examples to me seem to just be adding more and more steps to achieve the same goal. How/why are they used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't say this is the best practice, but this is what I use, and why, and here we go:

---

### 1. The repositories.

They are structured this way:

There are three basic interfaces, `IRead<>`, `IReadCreate<>` and `IReadCreateDelete<>`.

```
interface IRead<T>
{ 
    T FindOne(int id);
    IQueryable<T> GetOne(int id);
    IQueryable<T> FindAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
}

interface IReadCreate<T> : IRead<T>
{ 
    T Create();
    void Create(T entity);
}

interface IReadCreateDelete<T> : IReadCreate<T>
{ 
    void Delete(int id);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void DeleteWhere(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
}
```

The all other interfaces look like this:

```
interface ICategoriesRepository : IReadCreate<Category>
{
    IQueryable<Category> GetAllActive();
}
```

And all of them provides additional usefull functionality on the data source they depend on. It means, I cannot reach other typed repositories in my implementation repository. That should be done on **Services**. (Look below.)

The main goal of this approach is to show the calling code (from another assembly, because all my repositories, services and other contracts are defined (as interfaces) in separate DLL project) what it can do (like reading and creating items) and what it cannot do (like deleting items).

---

### 2. Services

Services and best way to implement your business logic. They should implement all your vital logic methods. To achive that kind of implementation they will need some repositories depency, and here it comes the `Dependency Injector`. I prefer to use **Ninject**, because it allows me to inject dependency properties like this:

```
internal class CategoriesService : ICategoryService
{
    public ICategoriesRepository CategoriesRepository { get; set; }
    public IWorkstationsRepository WorkstationsRepository { get; set; }

    // No constructor injection. I am too lazy for that, so the above properties 
    // are auto-injected with my custom ninject injection heuristic.

    public void ActivateCategory(int categoryId)
    {
        CategoriesRepository.FindOne(categoryId).IsActive = true;
    }
}
```

The goal of services is to eliminate business logic from controllers and from repositories.

---

### 3. ViewModels

Cool thing, as you told, but the reason is why are you building them up in theirselves is the thing I can't get. I am using the **automapper** for that (with its queryable extensions), which allows me to create views like this:

Let's say I have a **view** which needs an `IEnumerable<TicketViewModel>` model. What I do is:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
     public IMappingEngine Mapping { get; set; } // Thing from automapper.
     public ITicketsRepository TicketsRepository { get; set; }

     public ViewResult Tickes()
     { 
         return View(TicketsRepository.GetAllForToday().Project(Mapping)
             .To<TicketViewModel>().ToArray();
     }
}
```

That's it. Simple call to repository, which makes calls to underlying data source (another pattern. I wont write about it, because its abstraction is needed only for testing.), which makes calls to database (or whatever you implement `IDataSource<T>`). Automapper automappically maps the `Ticket` to `TicketViewModel` and form database I retrive **the only needed for my ViewModel columns, including the cross-table in a single request**.

---

### Conclusion

There are much to say more, but I hope this will give you some food for thought. All the patterns and programs I use are:

1. Automapper (mapping);
2. Ninject (dependency injection);
3. Repositories (data access);
4. Data Source (data reads from .. well.. from data source);
5. Services (data interactivity);
6. ViewModels (data transfer objects);
7. Maybe something else I'll edit to add about.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Based on this and other comments I am definitely missing the service layer. I am currently working with linq2sql as I am very new to mvc and c# so I didn't want to also fry my brain with EF also. Do any of your comments change based on linq2sql usage? I am assuming not due to it just being part of the data access, but thought I would check.

Comment: @munkee My comments were actually based on l2s.

Comment: Thanks and finally I haven't ever used automapper to know but does it handle view models which require columns from multiple tables and the creation of select lists etc? If so think its time I had a look into it as everything in your code looks much cleaner

Comment: @munkee yes it does. As I have been mentioned in my post.

Answer (score 3):

When I started reading your post I was thinking that maybe what you are looking for is an understanding of SOLID principles. And then you end by mentioning interfaces and service layers. Interesting.

There are plenty of articles celebrating the holy grail of SOLID and DRY (Many without understanding what DRY advocates are really proposing). But the general idea in the .NET world, is NOT to go to the autogenerated Page_Load in an aspx and start typing away all willy nilly until a page does what it is supposed to do. MVC to the rescue.

You say you have a model for each view. I would call that sound. Even if two models are identical, they are only equal, not the same. For example: A NewsItem is not an EventItem. If you want to expand on one, it should not effect the other.

Then you continue with saying you are producing your models in the view model itself. That sounds backwards. But you say you do so in order to keep your controller clean. Good! What is missing in your mindset, is services.

What you want to do is to move all code that actually perform any kind of work into services. A service can be based on an aspect, or on a feature or why not a control. Looking at one web project now, I see: VisitorService, NewsfeedService, CalendarService, CachingService, MainMenuService, HeaderService, FooterService etc etc ad infinitum.

In this scenario, the controller is only responsible for asking a service (or services),  that performs some work, for a model. And then forward that model to a view.

Once you got 'business logic' into services you can easily apply IoC (Inversion of Control) to your projects if that makes you happy. I have not cast my vote on IoC yet. I have the eerie the benefits is not as great as advertized, and you can do without the code bloat for sure. But IoC do ask of you to think before you code.

For a very easy going tutorial on IoC, I recommend Ninject. Not only does it feature Ninjas, but samurais, swords and shuriken as well. That's a lot cooler than cars and animals.

https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-By-Hand

Comment: Thank you for the info exactly what I have been looking for. I will look in to cleaning up some of my work with services. I assume IOC is none essential and something I can come back to at a later date?

Comment: Indeed. What you might want to do is first get all your logic into services. Next step could be making your Linq2Sql layer into a class library that only services may talk to. After that you could make those services that is depending on your data-layer into interfaces and try out ninject for IoC. Lastly you could make unit tests that mocks away your database.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers on how to begin re-working some of my code. If I were to start a new project, how much of all of these layers are worth the bang for the buck. At present our business is just venturing in to web apps and specifically using mvc c#. We are sticking with MS SQL Server for the foreseeable future and I can only presume it is a very rare case that people change their apps underlying database to a totally different set up. If that is the real world case are some of these layers overkill or just good practice (unit testing with mock really is a big plus)?

Comment: Getting all business logic into services increases code quality immensely. I follow this pattern even in my WebForms projects. As for IoC; I am a huge fan of Code Contracts but they are a PITA to add to interfaces, why IoC and CC not mix well. However, the idea with IoC is not to give Oracle support for your db. Rather to be able to switch some aspect of your db into simple classes that serves a unit test with predictable values.

Comment: I have just started reading pro asp.net mvc 3 framework by adam freeman and steven sanderson and it is really putting everything you have said in to context. Thanks for all the help now time to do some studying!

Comment: Forgot to mention a huge benefit: If you don't go to either extremes, sloppy vs solid, but find a good balance in-between: Then you will discover that going to work on monday morning is exhilarating! And you can leave friday afternoon feeling proud of your work. Personal gratification is a huge boon to code quality. =)

Answer (score 2):

**Controller:**

In theory your controller should be only handling "data". Moving pieces of information from one place to another.

Little example:

1. Controller receives request "GetMessage" with some parameter.
2. Sends this data to service layer. In service layer you are accessing
   repository returning message.
3. Cntroller receives this message (or if there were none null) and decides if it shoudl send received message back or maybe there was an error and user should be notified somehow.

All the business logic "in theory" should be behind some service layer. That way you can easilly test everything. Logic in controller makes some tests more difficult.

**Interfaces:**

Interface based design is very popular now. Especially with all the IOC Containers handling dependancy injection. But if you are starting with this concept don't bother about these keywords. If you know the Repository pattern, then try at first with IRepository interface and instead of accesing repository by concrete class, use IRepository. (Just change field in controller from Repository to IRepository).

[Generaly about interfaces](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/csharp_interrfaces03052006095933AM/csharp_interrfaces.aspx)

You will see the benefit of interfaces in more complex scenarios, but there is one technique that will show you all the glory of this approach. Unit Testing + Mocking.

Comment: I have to say one of the reasons I started asking myself the questions posted was because I wanted to get myself kicked off into learning unit testing (I have only been working with c# and mvc a couple of months) and it dawned on me how my current structure is a complete mess to try and test.

Comment: Thats good approach :) You know what you can do ? Read how to write first unit test in some framework like NUnit and try to write some test for one of the controllers :). With unit tests you can easilly check quality of your code by analysing how easily you can create test scenario. If you need like 1000 lines of code to initialize some specific scenario you immediately notice that something is wrong. You know "test" is only a by product of TDD the main focus of writing tests is to check your desing and code structure. By using your code you get fast feedback on the quality.

Comment: I have gone away and got myself up and running with interfaces and repositorys correctly. I am now trying to implement my service layer. Am I right in thinking my controller can reference both an interface to a repository and also a service layer. There may be times for instance when the service layer is not needed due to only retrieving data from a repository which I do through my interface. When I need my service layer it will reference interfaces to ensure data is retrieved/manipulated and essentially then pass back a signal to my controller that all is ok/not ok for the login to move on?

Comment: Hmm typically repository is inside service layer. Service layer should be used to manipulate crude data received from DB before sending to the view. For instance you can transform Models into ViewModels here. Your approach is ok. Every approach is ok it depends on the situation. Tbh you can't create perfect code. Get something to working state and even if you fail you will learn that this desing in this particular scenario was not needed or you are lacking something.

Comment: Ok so if I have this right I would have: View  -> Controller -> Service layer which may/may not then use Repository -> Database. If I then wish I can have interfaces between a controller and a service and also between a service and a repository? I can then use those interfaces for moq if I wish but I can then also unit test each and everyone of the above "layers". At the moment I have my repositorys sat within my Domain layer. So I have for example App.WebUI, App.Services, App.Domain.

Comment: Yep that is quite correct :) you know the benefit of service layer is that you can for instance create your own caching that can be aplied before sending data to the controller. Repository can sit in Domain.